# How I use nvm script in the rust?

Tags: node.js, rust, nvm

Firstly, I'm a Rust newbie.

recently, I want to write some rust code that help me to switch node version automaticaly in every frontend project.

so, I read some rust docs, I pick `std::process::Command` method to execute some shell script.
It looks like:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("nvm")
        .args(&["--version"])
        .output()
        .expect("faile");
}
```

And I `cargo run` above, I get the error: `faile: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }'`.
But I run `nvm --version` is work in my terminal. So confusing...

Comment: I think the way that `nvm` works is by sourcing a shell function into your environment, it's not an executable program on its own.

Comment: emm... Yes, It's work, I use `env` to find `nvm`'s path, and `bash -c ` execute it.
And I figured what, `std::process::Command` will fork a child process, so my main program process will never be changed!

Answer (score 0):

As isaactfa mentioned, nvm is not a program but is a shell script, and because of that, the default rust `std::process::Command` will not function on it correctly.

This is different to windows, where your current code will work.

However, there is a work around. You can use the [cmd_lib](https://github.com/rust-shell-script/rust_cmd_lib) crate. There are two methods and both are quite hacky.

---

### Method #1

The first method is to deploy your program with a shell script. This is an okay method if you only plan to use this locally.

First create a get_nvm.sh at you crate root (which will need to be placed at executed file when not run through `cargo run`).

**get_nvm.sh**

```
export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm;
source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh;
nvm --version
```

After adding cmd_lib via `cargo add cmd_lib`, you can use:

**main.rs**

```
use cmd_lib::run_fun;

fn main() {
     let output: String = run_fun!(bash get_nvm.sh).expect("Error");
}
```

---

### Method #2

The second method is to create the shell script then run it (and optionally delete it). This means all that needs to be distributed is the executable file.

**main.rs**

```
use std::{fs::{File, remove_file}, io::Write};
use cmd_lib::run_fun;

fn main() {
    // Create the file
    let mut file = File::create("get_nvm.sh")
        .expect("Error when making the file.");

    // Write to the file
    file.write_all(
        r#"export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm;
        source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh;
        nvm --version"#.as_bytes()
    ).expect("Error when writing to file.");

    // Run the file
    let output: String = run_fun!(bash get_nvm.sh).expect("Error");

    // OPTIONAL: Delete the file
    remove_file("./get_nvm.sh")
        .expect("Error when deleting the file.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to use `nvm` command.

```rust
fn main() {
    // firstly, find the nvm direction
    let nvm_dir = env::var("NVM_DIR").unwrap();

    let output = Command::new("bash")
        .arg("-c")
        // secondly, source the ${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh
        .arg(format!(". {}/nvm.sh", nvm_dir))
        // finally, you can execute nvm commands
        .args(&["nvm --version"]);
}
```

When I figured out above situation, I found that I can't reach my expected program. Cause the Rust only can **fork** the child process, and it can't make the main process env any changed!

Originly, I wanted to use the Rust's Command to switch node's version, when I entry a node's project.